# Should you expose JPA's in your view layer?

Tags: model-view-controller, jpa

In an MVC model, should you expose your JPA objects in the control/view layers or should you proxy those objects with another object. I'm not suggesting giving access to the DAO outside of the model layer, just the JPA objects. I see...
The benefit of using the JPA objects is that you don't have to needlessly copy all the data back and forth between the JPA and the proxy object. I guess the con is simply that it may not perfectly fit the MVC model to allow model layer objects visibily in the view layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's okay, unless there's a clear benefit to maintaining layer purity, or harm caused by passing model objects to the view layer.

I don't like the idea of parallel object hierarchies - it's a lot of work to create DTOs just for the sake of ferry data between layers for the sake of object purity.

I always thought it was caused by "chatty" communication between EJB 1.0 entity beans that inspired this anti-pattern.  Why keep it alive now that we have EJB 3.0?